# html to ppt using apache poi is not rendering html

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am using the following code to convert html to ppt using apache poi but it just copies the html code into ppt, rendering is not happening.

```
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.TextBox;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;


public class apachePOI {
     public static void main(String[]args){
          try{
           File file = new File("Hello.html");
           FileInputStream fis = null;
           BufferedInputStream bis = null;
           DataInputStream dis = null;
           fis = new FileInputStream(file);
           bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
           dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
           String st="";
           while (dis.available() != 0) {
            st+=dis.readLine().toString()+"\n";
           }
           System.out.println(st);
           SlideShow slideShow = new SlideShow();
           Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
           TextBox txt = new TextBox();
           txt.setText(st+" ");
           slide.addShape(txt);
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Hello.ppt");
           slideShow.write(out);
           out.close();
           bis.close();
           dis.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e){}
         }
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I am not aware of a PowerPoint TextBox in POI that would automatically render HTML. Is rendering the data yourself an option?

Comment: i mean the file should be displayed as a page(as ppt of a webpage) in powerpoint slide.

Comment: You would then need a Web Browser Element in PowerPoint; this does exist, but to the best of my knowledge can't be done from POI.